# How to prove that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Suppose that $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with $A^3 = A$. Then prove that $A$ is diagonalizable.

I have proved it using the concept that minimal polynomial of $A$ consists of only linear factors. But without applying this method I couldn't able to solve it in an alternative way.

Please let me aware if there were any alternative way of solving this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What "alternative way" might you be interested in?  Can we us Jordan form?

Comment: I don't actually know Jordan form. Is there any other way?

Comment: Well what do you know?  Do you have any particular reason for avoiding using minimal polynomials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an interesting approach: note that
$$
x = (I - A^2)x + \frac 12(A^2 - A)x + \frac 12(A^2 + A)x
$$
Because $A^3 - A = 0$, note that $(I - A^2)x \in \ker(A)$, $(A^2 - A)x \in \ker(A + I)$, and $(A^2 + A)x \in \ker(A - I)$.  Thus, we have shown that any vector in $\Bbb C^n$ can be decomposed into a linear combination of eigenvectors.

Comment: You @om have actually shown that $\mathbb C^n$ is the direct sum of the eigen spaces of $A$ and consequently $A$ is diagonalizable. Isn't it?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Very nice one!!

Comment: Would the eigenvalues for these eigenvectors be necessarily 1, -1, or 0? @Omnomnomnom . Since eigenvectors and eigenvalues are found by looking for kernel(A-lamda*I) ? Thanks.

Comment: @H_1317 that's right.